# Render multiple boxs with LineSegment in threejs

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I am using `InstancedMesh` to render multiple blocks, but I also want to add an outline to each block. However, I haven't found a method similar to `InstancedMesh` for optimizing the outlines, so I would like to ask for advice from the community.

```js
const instancedMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, this.getMetarial(), block.length);
const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
const offset = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const blockLineGroup = new THREE.Group();


for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  const { geometry, xOffset, yOffset, zOffset } = createGeometry(data[i]);

  // next instance
  offset.x = xOffset - baseOffset.xOffset;
  offset.y = yOffset - baseOffset.yOffset;
  offset.z = zOffset - baseOffset.zOffset;

  matrix.makeTranslation(offset.x, offset.y, offset.z);
  instancedMesh.setMatrixAt(i, matrix);

  const blockLine = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(lineGeometry), lineMaterial);
  blockLineGroup.add(blockLine);
}

this.blocksGroup.add(instancedMesh);
this.linesGroup.add(blockLineGroup);
```

I ask to the chatgpt for the question, and useless:

```js
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
const lineSegmentsGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(boxGeometry);

const instanceGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
instanceGeometry.index = lineSegmentsGeometry.index;
instanceGeometry.attributes.position = lineSegmentsGeometry.attributes.position;

const numInstances = block.length;
const instanceMatrix = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(numInstances * 16), 16);
for (let i = 0; i < numInstances; i++) {
  const [x, y, z, width, height, depth] = block[i];
  const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  matrix.makeTranslation(x + width / 2, y + height / 2, z + depth / 2);
  matrix.toArray(instanceMatrix.array, i * 16);
}

instanceGeometry.addAttribute('instanceMatrix', instanceMatrix);

const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({...});

const lineSegments = new THREE.InstancedMesh(lineSegmentsGeometry, material, numInstances);
lineSegments.instanceMatrix.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage); 
lineSegments.geometry = instanceGeometry;

this.linesGroup.add(lineSegments);
```

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/XWKYLqW